# Sharepoint list pulling in document names from another library with clickable links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a large document library which holds currently 1000+ files. Some of these files are important announcements, so my plan was to have a separate list to show them.

For example. The list would pull in the name of a document using lookup. Which I have done.
I then have a choice column to set to either, Current, Superseded or Withdrawn. 
Then finally a third column which once again pulls in a list of names from the same library.

The plan would be to pick a document, say Announcement222, this would appear in the list as a clickable link which opens the file directly. I would change another column to Superseded and then pick another file, Announcement224.

This would in 3 columns show users what announcements are active and if any are superseded, by why document.

Is all this possible using SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a separate list, you should just use a listview webpart filtered to the files you want to show.

For guidance on creating filtered views, see [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-server-f3ac35a0-4148-4573-a6e1-cad0a9e28037).

For displaying a list view on another page, see [here for modern pages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537) and [here for classic pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff806162(v%3Doffice.14)).